# How to show UIActivityView while call a function that perform any operation? - objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a `UITableView` and when I touch a row of its I call `myFunction` that perform any operation and then reload the table.
Now I want to show an `UIActivityIndicator` while I call `myFunction`. What is the approach followed in these cases?

This is my code:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionview didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {

[self showLoader];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myFunction:) withObject:indexPath];
[self hideLoader];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some Delay in your Call :

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionview didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath 
{
      [self showLoader];
      [self performSelector:@selector(myFunction:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:1.0];
      [self hideLoader];
}
```

GoodLuck...!!!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use this [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

This is good example for calling UIActivityIndicator while loading data.

Answer (score 0):

In This code `UIActivityIndicator` display in **statusBar**

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionview didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    [self showLoader];
    [self performSelector:@selector(myFunction:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:1.0];

    [self hideLoader];
    }
```

and for stop `UIActivityIndicator` write following code at end of `myFunction`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
```